# Ensuring Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin is frequent in all Apache virtual hosts whatsoever

Tags: text-processing, apache-httpd, symlink, control-flow, phpmyadmin

I use Debian and Apache and say I have many virtual host files (above 20) and I want all of them to include this line in the end:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

The reason is to allow to navigate from the domain of each web app (per virtual host file) to PHPMyAdmin easy and fast, as in:

```
example-1.com/phpmyadmin
example-2.com/phpmyadmin
```

What is an efficient way to do so (that will also filter out virtual host files that might already include this line by manual addition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the package-provided configuration in `phpmyadmin` adds the alias in all virtual hosts: it adds a top-level

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

entry in the Apache configuration.

When installing non-interactively, you need to ensure that the Apache 2 configuration is selected in `phpmyadmin`’s `debconf`, which might require pre-seeding.

Comment: It will be added even for virtual hosts created after PMA was installed as a Debian package, right?

Comment: Yes, it’s a global configuration.